# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-widget

I am new in Flutter and I am trying receive data with a Dialog.
When a click in textField the error of image2 appear...

[image: Layout's Image]
[image: Error's Image]

```
show(BuildContext context){

    var dialog = Dialog(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Insira o número de telefone",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)))),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text("Cancelar")),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text("Aceitar"))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    showDialog(context: context,builder: (context){
      return dialog;
    });
  }
```

This is my code.

```
I/flutter (31032): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
I/flutter (31032): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a
I/flutter (31032): widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling
I/flutter (31032): inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
I/flutter (31032):
```

Answer (score 116):

Declare a global variable

```
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then register the key on your widget build's scaffold eg

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       key: _scaffoldKey,
       ...
```

then on the dialog

```
show(BuildContext context){

var dialog = Dialog(
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Form(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Insira o número de telefone",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)))),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Cancelar")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Aceitar"))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Pass that scaffold context to the showDialog method

```
showDialog(context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext ,builder: (context){
  return dialog;
 });
}
```

Comment: thanks! this helped me with one of my dialogs, but i have another page which whenever loggs in successfully i pop using ```navigator.of(context)..pop()..pop()..pop("yes")``` but when dialog is shown i face this error, i used a scaffold key and also the builder.

Comment: This works for me having a big calling project.. which has multiple roles types .. passing scaffold.currentContext! has solved the issues as I was using the function for multiple roles of pages. Kudos to solution !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain why this works a bit?

Comment: ``Navigator.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!).pop();`` to close dialog

Answer (score 74):

**Try This**

Give different context name for dialog

```
 showDialog(context: context,builder: (dialogContex){
              return Dialog(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Form(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Insira o número de telefone",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)))),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(dialogContex).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text("Cancelar")),
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text("Aceitar"))
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
```

Comment: this answer is technically right as we need to remove dialog so we should give diffrent name to dialog context

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I have a dialog with edit text fields and also a loading dialog, naming the contexts separates them and I am able to close both successfully!

Comment: You can create a buildContext variable and assign context to it. Then you can pass that newly created variable to showDialog method.

Answer (score 28):

I got the same error when attempting to open a dialog and I found a solution here: [github flutter issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19462#issuecomment-478284020). Specifically, I followed the poster's recommendation, which was to create a `GlobalKey` and associate it with the `Scaffold` widget, and use the context from that key when creating the dialog. In my case, I have a globally accessible object which holds the `GlobalKey`:

```
MyGlobals myGlobals = MyGlobals();
class MyGlobals {
  GlobalKey _scaffoldKey;
  MyGlobals() {
    _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  }
  GlobalKey get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;
}
```

In the `Scaffold` widget constructor call:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: ...,
  body: ...,
  drawer: ...,
  key: myGlobals.scaffoldKey,
)
```

And in the `showDialog` call:

```
showDialog<String>(
  barrierDismissible: ...,
  builder: ...,
  context: myGlobals.scaffoldKey.currentContext,
);
```

Comment: @ajs.sonawane Do you mean that it doesn't work when you create a dialog from within a dialog, or it doesn't work when you try to use it a second time with the same dialog, or that it doesn't work if you use it for one dialog, close that dialog, and then open a different dialog?

Comment: nope, calling dialog then popping it and then calling it again

Comment: @ajs.sonawane It seems to be working for my situation ... perhaps you will need to post a new question. Sorry.

Answer (score 21):

You’re trying to access a context that isn’t probably available. That happens because you’ve assigned your `Dialog` to a `var` and afterwards use a different context (the one from your dialog builder).

Either create your dialog directly after your `return` in the builder or make it a method instead that returns a `Dialog` and pass it a  `BuildContext` parameter.

```
Widget myDialog(BuildContext context) => Dialog(/*your dialog here*/);
```

This is also a more convenient Flutter practice. You should use methods that return widgets instead of assigning it to variables.

Comment: You need to provide more code context/info then. At first glance that's what it seems, because when you are popping the `Dialog` you may be referring to an invalid widget context.

Comment: This is **not** a convenient flutter practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/10122791

Answer (score 21):

use this:

```
Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

instead of

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? Why / in which cases is the latter preferable?

Comment: For Explaination please visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349741/what-is-the-use-of-rootnavigator-in-navigator-ofcontext-rootnavigator-true

Comment: This will not necessarily help. 
If your context is outdated, this might still fail, as even with the `rootNavigator: true` part you are still accessing a `BuildContext` that is no longer viable.

Also: you might discover unwanted navigation behaviour, e.g., when you use tab bars.

Answer (score 9):

This might happen while you are popping from the context and trying to open new content on the context you are popping.

```
()async{
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    _alertPopUp(); // shows a dialog
    // might do some work after
}
```

if alert dialog is created on current context then it throws an error because context doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I was using hot reload for pretty long time, I think at some point everything got messed up, doing a normal run of the app fixed the problem.

Comment: Seems like this is the answer which worked i dont know if flutter could be notified of this issue

Answer (score 3):

Use this if You are using Stack in AlertDialog Not Closing on Navigator.of(context).pop();

```
late NavigatorState _navigator;

   @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {

    _navigator = Navigator.of(context);

    super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

Use This

```
 Positioned(right: 10.0,child: GestureDetector(

                  // behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,

                  onTap: () {
                    _navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 14.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.close, color: black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

removing application from emulator and run below commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

works for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug, but in totally different context. I use Riverpod as a state manager, and I wanted to cancel a stream in StatefulWidget dispose method. It turned out that it caused this bug. What I had to do is to use Riverpod's `onDispose` API.

```
ref.onDispose(() {
    batteryStateSubscription.cancel();
});
```

[A full example](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose#example-canceling-http-requests-when-no-longer-used) is shown in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

before calling a dialog when a page is just loading, call it by adding SchedulerBinding to it, call it like this

`SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showDialog( context: context, barrierDismissible: false, builder: (context) { return dialogBox(context, "Fetching account data", 'Profile page', DialogType.processing, function: () {}, dismissText: "", ); }));`

Answer (score 1):

Though you got desired answer, just for better clarification for others I put my opinion here.

**Reason :**
It is happend due to context mismatch issue. Your passing context to Navigator.of(context).pop() is not matching with your MainApp BuildContext.

**Solution :** There has 2 way

1. U can use Global key
2. pass actual context to your Navigator

Below link I already mentioned how to solve this by passing actual context

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543251/6109034

Answer (score 1):

calling Navigator.pop(context) at the beginning of async function worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First let's understand what the framework is saying:

Point - 1:

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point
> the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

This simply means that the widget(parent of Dialog) is no longer present in the widget tree and it can be confirmed by checking the result of `context.mounted` property. This can be solved by providing a valid `BuildContext` to the child just by wrapping the Dialog with a `Builder` class. You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123080/19368196) to understand the significance of `Builder`.

```
show(BuildContext context){
var dialog = Dialog(
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Form(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Insira o número de telefone",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)))),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Cancelar")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Aceitar"))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

showDialog(
   context: context,
   // Wrapping the clild widget (dialog) within a Builder class.
   builder: (context) => Builder(
     builder: (context) {
      return dialog;
      },
    ),
  );
 }
```

Point - 2:

> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in
> the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

This simply asks us to save the context(reference to the parent widget) before it gets de-activated. The suggestions to use GlobalKey in the above answers simply does the same. As GlobalKey is unique throughout the application, the context is preserved. However, one can also save the context using state management.

Answer (score 1):

i get answer with this snippet :

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    Navigator.of(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Future<AlertDialog> myDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<AlertDialog>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Insira o número de telefone",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("Cancelar")),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("Aceitar"))
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's akward, I've tested it myself and worked fine

Comment: Can you post here the complete example, please ?

Answer (score 0):

declare dialog and set in `initState`

```
  late Dialog dialog;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dialog = Dialog(
      ...
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a provider where I used a context as an argument to a function, the thing was that when I passed that page I did it with pushnamedAndRemove Until then on the next page I was trying to use a function where I required the above context, so the error was mine because it was trying to get a parameter that I destroyed earlier, for that reason it didn't work. So be careful if you are deleting old pages.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.' while working with GetX. Initially, I utilized the 'GetMaterialApp' widget in the main function to launch the app:

```
void main() => runApp(
  DevicePreview(
    enabled: true,
    builder: (context) => GetMaterialApp(home: const MyApp()), // Wrap your app
  ),
);
```

However, after switching to the conventional MaterialApp, the issue was resolved:

```
void main() => runApp(
  DevicePreview(
    enabled: true,
    builder: (context) => MaterialApp(home: const MyApp()), // Wrap your app
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I simply solved this by wrapping the showDialog with a Builder widget, though for me the error came from a stream builder I simply wrap the stream builder with a builder widget and the remove the notify listeners from the a stream am calling in the stream builder, but in your case wrap the showDialog with a Builder widget and it will use the context from the builder, problem solved

Answer (score -1):

**first :** declare a FormKey.

```
 GlobalKey<FormState>myFormKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

**second :** add the FormKey to your Form widget.

```
Form( 

 key:myFormKey,

 child:child

 )
```

Comment: your example is not related please explain some clearly

Answer (score -3):

In my case i was calling

```
setState(() {
   Navigator.pop(context);
});
```