# What is the use of `rootNavigator` in Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push();

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the difference between

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/route");
```

and

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/route");
```

More importantly, what's the use of setting `rootNavigator: true` on `Navigator` class, I read docs but they aren't quite clear. Can anyone explain the difference properly?

Comment: If you're using a nested Navigator and you want to navigate from a screen that is inside the nested Navigator to a screen that is part of the top-level Navigator, then you have to set rootNavigator to true. You can read more about this here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to see an example of it, if you can show.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
There is a `root Navigator` above tab navigation 
This demo shows open(`Navigator.push`) a full screen dialog (`fullscreenDialog: true`) with `rootNavigator true/false`

picture 
`rootNavigator` = `true` , `fullscreenDialog` take all screen and above `tab` 
`rootNavigator` = `false`, `fullscreenDialog` take `tab` size and inside `tab`, you can switch between `Home` and `Support` tab and see `fullscreenDialog` is still there

[image]

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
  Center(
    child: CupertinoButton(
      child: const Text(
        'Push rootNavigator true',
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
          CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
            fullscreenDialog: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Tab3Dialog(),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  Center(
    child: CupertinoButton(
      child: const Text(
        'Push rootNavigator false',
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).push(
          CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
            fullscreenDialog: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Tab3Dialog(),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PawzHome(),
    );
  }
}

class PawzHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.conversation_bubble),
            title: Text('Support'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return CupertinoDemoTab1();
              },
              defaultTitle: 'Colors',
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoDemoTab2(),
              defaultTitle: 'Support Chat',
            );
            break;
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoDemoTab1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([Tab1RowItem()]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tab1RowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
          title: "Click me",
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Tab1ItemPage(),
        ));
      },
      child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: Text("Click me")),
    );
  }
}

class Tab1ItemPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 100,),
              Center(
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Push rootNavigator true',
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                      CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
                        fullscreenDialog: true,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Tab3Dialog(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Push rootNavigator false',
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).push(
                      CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
                        fullscreenDialog: true,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Tab3Dialog(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class CupertinoDemoTab2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Tab 2"),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Tab3Dialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        leading: CupertinoButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
          },
          child: Text("Ok"),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
          child: const Text('Sign in'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @chunhunghan, I'm trying to achieve a similar thing with a bottom sheet. In my case, it seems that the use of `useRootNavigator` doesn't have any effect. Here is a gist if you don't mind having a look https://gist.github.com/alexgrusu/8fd173e56d4046cdbda487e4b98bd950.

Answer (score 19):

If your app has nested navigators this parameter comes in handy when you want to call the root navigator not it's nested navigators ... please consider the image bellow ... in this example we are inside the page 2 and we want the page 3 to be the rootNavigator's child *(because for example we want to ignore the bottomNavigationBar that is in MainPage)*... in this example if you don't set the `rootNavigator = true` and you push the page 3 it will be the nestedNavigator's child *(So the BottomNavigationBar of the MainPage's will be still visible)*.
[image]

Comment: If you have `bottomNavigationBar` in `MainPage` and you navigate to the `Page3` using the nested navigator, the bottom navigation bar will not be visible (tested in both Android/iOS).

Comment: Then, how should I move back to page2? I have a video player on page3