# Navigator.push opens a page BELOW TabBar but I need it to open the page fullscreen

Tags: flutter

I have a TabBar and in one of the tabs there are buttons that redirect to pages. When I click on the button, it should just open the page. However, when clicked, it opens the page underneath the TabBar as shown in the picture below. How can I make it so that the page opens on the entire page?

I made a custom Widget for my buttons:

```
class CalendarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  String bgImage = "";
  String title = "";
  String page = "";

  CalendarButton(
      {required this.bgImage, required this.title, required this.page});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Ink.image(
        image: AssetImage(
          bgImage,
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (page == 'FP') {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => FP(),
                ),
              );
            } else if (page == 'MS') {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MS(),
                ),
              );
            } else if (page == 'HS') {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HS(),
                ),
              );
            } else if (page == 'Year') {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Year(),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[What the screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdBz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(...)`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372154/3407244