# Use a single BottomNavBar in flutter to navigate the entire app

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a problem that I can't solve. I'm new to flutter and would like to make a BottomNavBar that allows me to navigate through my project. So I have 3 navigation elements, which work very well. However, I have interactions in these elements, and I would like to regenerate the pages created in the navigation directly, instead of having to regenerate everything. So I would like the new pages to replace the current body.

To be more clear, here is an image of what I want to do:

Here is the user page (composed of Sign in and Sign up, but will therefore generate a new page depending on what we choose):
[User Page Sign in Sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MpWj.png)

And so I want when I click on sign up, it goes directly to the current body instead of opening a new page and therefore breaking my whole structure (This is an example here, I just copied and pasted the elements of the Sign Up Sign in page, but after there will be the forms):
[SignUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ZtQ.png)

I'd be really glad if someone could help me out, as I've been stuck on this for hours

Comment: share code snippet

Comment: Do you want the newly generated page to replace the current page as in have the bottom nav still available?

Comment: I guess nested Navigator is what you want. Flutter app can have nested navigators. For example you have 3 elements in bottom menu and you create 3 nested navigators (1 for each element of menu). Each nested navigator will contain pages for each bottom menu element separatly from each other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe navigating with the `rootNavigator: true` can help.

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/route");`

I think you can take a look at this thread: [What is the use of `rootNavigator` in Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349741/what-is-the-use-of-rootnavigator-in-navigator-ofcontext-rootnavigator-true)

I hope I am not misunderstanding your question.