# Flutter: Pressing back Button on Android when Dialog is open causes Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe error

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, navigator

i am using this elevated button:

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: () {
    _showConfirmationPayement(request);
    },
```

and this is my dialog method:

```
_showConfirmationPayement(Request request) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(request.status == "Open"
              ? "Confirm payment?"
              : "Cancel pending payment?"),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(request.status == "Open"
                    ? "Have you paid for this transaction?"
                    : "This will make the request status to 'Not paid'"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text("No")),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: ()  {
                    showDialog(
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ));
                    request.status == "Open"
                        ? request.status = "Pending"
                        : request.status = "Open";

                     RequestController.updateRequestRecord(request);

                

                    if (mounted ) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                  
                },
                child: const Text("Yes"))
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

i am trying to have a CircularLoading Process indicator when the update method is being called inside the 'yes' button function, but if i press the android's device back button it results to a  Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe error. I have tried changing the name of the context inside the dialog and also use a scaffoldKey as these threads suggest: [Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617432/looking-up-a-deactivated-widgets-ancestor-is-unsafe)
,but nothing worked. How can i handle the user if the user presses the android back button to cancel all activity in the dialog and pop back to the main screen?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.